# Half precision floating points texture filtering in CUDA

Tags: cuda, filtering, textures, precision

Can I take advantage of CUDA texture filtering when using *16-bit float* texture type? I have already made test with *32-bit float* texture in CUDA 3D Array and filtering works fine. CUDA doesn't support *unsigned short* texture interpolation, which would be perfect for me, as it occupies less memory space.

<strike>I'm thinking about this solution - correct me if i'm wrong:</strike>

- convert my *unsigned short* data to *16-bit floats* in range [0;1]; (how?)
- malloc 3D array width `cudaCreateChannelDescHalf()` channel descriptor
- bind texture of *unsigned short* data to that array
- send it to the GPU memory, into the 3D array;
- in kernel - use `tex3D()` function to get values

See answer below...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Again I answer my own question. Next time I'll try to dig more before posting here...

I think the problem was with the texture declaration:

```c
texture<unsigned short, cudaTextureType3D, cudaReadModeNormalizedFloat> tex;
```

Filtering, as I see, is supported only if the returned value is *float* type, which can be forced with `cudaReadModeNormalizedFloat` as above. Then `tex3D` returns [0;1] interpolated float value.